# MinimalCD for beta version of Ubuntu?

Tags: release-management

I've got an older server that's being difficult. It has a CD drive, but it won't accept a DVD drive.

I would like to repurpose this old server and install Ubuntu 14 on it. Past versions of Ubuntu have provided a [MinimalCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) for installation.

Does anyone know if Ubuntu is still building them? It seems Ubuntu 8-13 have them, but 14 is missing.

If Ubuntu 14 is included, would anyone know where to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ubuntu 14.04 will be released: April 17th - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseSchedule

Before the final release the mini.iso  images can be found:

- http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/
- http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/